# Check if all items can be found in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check if all items in an array can be found within another array. That is, I need to check if one array is a subset of another array.

Example:

```
var array = [1, 2, 5, 7];
var otherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Comparing these two arrays above should return true as all items in `array` can be found in `otherArray`.

```
var array = [1, 2, 7, 9];
var otherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Comparing these two arrays above should return false as one of the items in `array` cannot be found in `otherArray`.

I have tried to use the `indexOf` method inside a for loop without success.
I hope someone could help me. :)

Comment: Do you know ahead of time if the arrays are always sorted?

Comment: If `otherArray` is large, it would be best to convert it to an object whose keys are the elements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 7, 9];
var otherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var isSubset = array.every(function(val) {
  return otherArray.indexOf(val) >= 0;
})

document.body.innerHTML = "Is array a subset of otherArray? " + isSubset;
```