# Checking the values of two Arrays using Includes

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

Is there any best way of find elements of two arrays?

In this code below I want to pass through this if the condition

> I want the best way of solving this problem

```js
const x =["a"]
const y =["a",3]
const z =["a",undefined,3]

for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
  x[1]=i
  console.log(x)
  if(x.includes(y)){
    console.log("i an in")
  }
  if(x.includes(z)){
    console.log("i am in")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there are three array but checking is done with two arrays only

Comment: That three array is just for the conditions that can appear when checking two array. So what is the best solution checking two arrays

Comment: Give me a minute I will try to create a  minimal reproducible example

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.every()` in a way described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989813/2610061

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you want to check array `x` include the array `y` (or not) and vice versa.

Then you can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) & [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like below:

```js
const x =["a"];
const y =["a", 3];
const z =["a", undefined, 3];

const checkInclude = (a, b) => b.every(v1 => a.includes(v1)); // The same as b.every(v1 => a.some(v2 => v1 === v2));

console.log("x include y: " + checkInclude(x, y));
console.log("y include x: " + checkInclude(y, x));
console.log("z include y: " + checkInclude(z, y));
```

---

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
> test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

Comment: Yes, `z include y: true`. I've just added one more check. Pls take a look at @RanjanRajShrestha